# How to use foreach / forv to replace duplicates in an increasing order

Tags: foreach, stata, data-cleaning

I have a "raw" data set that I´m trying to clean. The data set consists of individuals with the variable `age` between year 2000 and 2010. There are around 20000 individuals in the data set with the same problem.

The variable `age` is not increasing in the years 2004-2006. For example, for one individual it looks like this:

```
2000: 16, 
2001: 17,
2002: 18,
2003: 19,
2004: 19,
2005: 19,
2006: 19,
2007: 23,
2008: 24,
2009: 25,
2010: 26,
```

So far I have tried to generate variables for the max age and max year:

```
bysort id: egen last_year=max(year)
bysort id: egen last_age=max(age)
```

and then use `foreach` combined with lags to try to replace `age` variable in decreasing order so that when the new variable `last_age` (that now are 26 in all years)  rather looks like this:

```
2010: 26
2009: 25 (26-1)
2008: 24 (26-2) , and so on.
```

However, I have some problem with finding the correct code for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that for each individual the first value of age is not missing and is correct, something like this might work

```
bysort id (year): replace age = age[1]+(year-year[1])
```

Alternatively, if the last value of age is assumed to always be accurate,

```
bysort id (year): replace age = age[_N]-(year[_N]-year)
```

Or, just fix the ages where there is no observation-to-observation change in age

```
bysort id (year): replace age = age[_n-1]+(year-year[_n-1]) if _n>1 & age==age[_n-1]
```

In the absence of sample data none of these have been tested.

Answer (score 0):

William's code is very much to the point, but a few extra remarks won't fit easily into a comment.

Suppose we have `age` already and generate two other estimates going forward and backward as he suggests:

```
bysort id (year): gen age2 = age[1] + (year - year[1])
bysort id (year): gen age3 = age[_N] - (year[_N] - year)
```

Now if all three agree, we are good, and if two out of three agree, we will probably use the majority vote. Either way, that is the median; the median will be, for 3 values, the sum MINUS the minimum MINUS the maximum.

```
gen median = (age + age2 + age3) - max(age, age2, age3) - min(age, age2, age3)
```

If we get three different estimates, we should look more carefully.

```
edit age* if max(age, age2, age3) > median & median > min(age, age2, age3)
```

A final test is whether medians increase in the same way as years:

```
bysort id (year) : assert (median - median[_n-1]) == (year - year[_n-1]) if _n > 1
```